# Magento 1 backend not accessible (css and js not loaded)

Tags: css, magento

My Magento 1 backend only shows the raw form without css and jss here: https://www.xishi.de/admin

Checking the path of the URLs it says for example:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.xishi.de/admin/skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css" media="all" />
```

As you can see there is an added /admin/ in the url which should not be there.

My config settings:
[image: core_config_data]

Cleared the cache and tried various combinations of _url paths.

Answer (score 0):

omfg... as you can see in my picture magento added two web/secure/base_url paths.
The second one is wrong.

Whover wrote this shitty piece of software shall go straigt to hell and never write software again! I got nightmares of all the shitty bugs this ecommerce plattform produces.

We are moving to a Wordpress store which is way easier to setup and maintain then magento.